# git clone error,Connection refused while accessing ... info/refs

Tags: git, git-clone

i want to clone resource from my git server through http,but i got the following error:

```
git clone http://xxx/ResMonitor.git/
Cloning into ResMonitor...
error: Failed connect to xxx:80; Connection refused while accessing
http://xxx/ResMonitor.git/info/refs
```

i tried to run "git update-server-info" on the server , but it still doesn't work.
(i can access http://xxx/ResMonitor.git/info/refs through my chrome from client side)

can any one help? many thanks!

Comment: May be some rights issues? i.e. `www-data` might not be able to access  the repo config.